# Helgrind reports data race on single thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, valgrind

When attempting to create a single thread that only reads and prints its own argument and then returns, helgrind finds a lot of possible data races, despite the fact that the main thread performs pthread_join as soon as the new thread is created.

Here is the thread initialization (a scaled-down version that still reproduces the problem):

```
void liveness(cfg_t* cfg)
{
    vertex_t*               u;
    size_t                  i;
    size_t*                 arg;
    pthread_t               thread;
    pthread_mutex_t*        lock;

    lock = (pthread_mutex_t*) malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
    if (lock == NULL) {
        printf("Error when allocating memory for locks");
    }
    if (pthread_mutex_init(lock, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("Error when creating lock\n");
    }

    arg = malloc(sizeof(size_t));
    (*arg) = 0;
    if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, thread_start, arg)) {
        perror("Error when creating thread\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pthread_join(thread, NULL)) {               
        perror("Error when joining thread\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    free(lock);
    free(arg); //244
}
```

and this is thread_start

```
void* thread_start(void* arguments)
{
    size_t          index;
    index = * (size_t*) arguments; /155
    printf("Thread started! Index %zu\n", index);
    fflush(stdout);
    return NULL;
}
```

The output is correct (Thread started! Index 0) but helgrind produces the following output

```
==3489== Possible data race during write of size 8 at 0x4003330 by thread #1
==3489== Locks held: none
==3489==    at 0x42970F: _int_free (in /h/d9/b/dat11ote/courses/edan25/lab4home/live)
==3489==    by 0x402D5C: liveness (paralleldataflow.c:244)
==3489==    by 0x401E4F: main (main.c:134)
==3489==
==3489== This conflicts with a previous read of size 8 by thread #2
==3489== Locks held: none
==3489==    at 0x402C4C: thread_start (paralleldataflow.c:155)
==3489==    by 0x4040B1: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==3489==    by 0x4500E8: clone (in /h/d9/b/dat11ote/courses/edan25/lab4home/live)
```

and 30 more errors from 25 contexts. If i change the return statement to go before the thread argument as in

```
void* thread_start(void* arguments)
{
    size_t          index;
    return NULL;
}
```

then everything works fine. I use the -pthreads and -static flags to gcc. If I remove the printf and fflush, this leaves the error above but removes all the other errors, which looked like:

```
Possible data race during write of size 8 at 0x6D7878 by thread #1
Locks held: none
at 0x40F449: vfprintf (in /h/../live)
by 0x419075: printf (in /h/../live)
by 0x401E76: main (main.c:137)
This conflicts with a previous write of size 8 by thread #2
Locks held: none
at 0x40F449: vfprintf (in /h/../live)
by 0x419075: printf (in /h/../live)
by 0x402C68: thread_start (in /h/../live)
by 0x404061: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
by 0x44B2A8: clone (in /h/../live)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of "lock" mutex?

Comment: As of right now, nothing, though I want to use it later when the thread(s) work as expected (previously it was passed as part of a struct together with some other arguments, and there where several threads). I tried removing the reference to it altogether, but it doesn't fix anything.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the library functions from the thread callback? printf and fflush.

Comment: @Lundin - This removes all the other helgrind errors except for the one in the originial post. I edited it with an example of the errors that this fixes, if that helps.

Comment: @OlleTO The standard library is usually risky to use inside threads. It doesn't explain the race condition diagnostic you are getting though.

Comment: @OlleTO What happens if you declare "arg" as "volatile"?

Comment: GiuseppeGuerrini - Unfortunately, this didn't change anything.  
@Lundin - Thanks for the heads-up, I'll keep that in mind =)  

I did some poking around and appearently the '-static' flag was passed to the linker. Removing that flag fixes the problem, but I am unsure as to why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use -static to link, then it means that valgrind/helgrind
cannot replace or wrap a set of functions that must be replaced/wrapped
to have helgrind working properly.

Typically, to have helgrind working properly, functions such as malloc/free/...
must be replaced.
Functions such as pthread_create/pthread_join/... must be wrapped by helgrind.

Using static library means these functions are not replaced or wrapped,
causing a lot of false positive.